# Can i check nForce405/geforce6100 MCP temperature on linux?

Tags: temperature, sensors

Aida64 on windows show MCP (a southbridge-like chip) temperature as 50C.
Lm-sensors doesn't show it at all.

My motherboard is an Asrock k8nf6g-vsta. Here's what `sensors` shows:

[image]

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 with `sensors` version 3.3.4.

Here's the `sensors-detect` output:

```
"Driver `w83627ehf':
* ISA bus, address 0x290
Chip `Winbond W83627EHF/EF/EHG/EG Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `k8temp' (autoloaded):
* Chip `AMD K8 thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)"
```

And `/etc/modules`:

```
"w83627ehf"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that one of the three `temp*` temperatures shown in the `sensors` is your "MCP" temperature. `lm-sensors` isn't very good at labelling things. It just stacks the I²C monitoring interfaces up as it finds them.

But short of holding a blow-torch to your MCP and watching the output, I'm not sure how to confirm that one way or the other.

For *graphics* cards I have had limited success with `lmsensors` in the past. What I find works really well is `nvidia-smi` (from a package of the same name). This might not work for integrated chipsets very well but here's what I see on a discrete card:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Thu Jul  3 09:48:44 2014       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.17     Driver Version: 340.17         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 580     Off  | 0000:03:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 36%   50C   P12    N/A /  N/A |    520MiB /  1535MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry my bad english.Nvidia-smi output : [link](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140703/nvidiasmi_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png).Temp2 is cpu core ,tested with mprime,and temp1-2-3 not change when i remove air cooler from chipset.